# if condition for my grade rank in js, i'm quite confused on what's the problem

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need help resolving a problem with my code.

I want to get the score that's in the score id, and use it in an if condition wherein I will determine their grade rank.

I shouldn't be typing a value in p tag

Below is the code specific to the problem - All the ones that are needed should be below.

Thank you for the help guysss

i added some more code

```
<button id = "submit" name = "submit"  value = "submit"  > SUBMIT </button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3> Are you sure you want to submit? </h3>
        <button id = "yes" name = "yes" class = "yes" value = "submit" > YES </button>
        <button id = "no" name = "no" class = "no"> NO </button>
      </div>
    </div>





    <div id="myModalLast" class="modalLast">
      <div class="modal-contentLast">
       <a href = "personal.php"> <span class="close">&times;</span> </a>

    <div class = "pic">
        <img src="Logo.png" width = "150" height = "150">
    </div>  
        <h3> Full name: Cathleen Joyce Imperial Almeda </h3>  
        <h3> Total items:20 <p id = "scoree" name = "realscores"></p> </h3>  
       <h1> <br><p id = "scorees" name = "realscores"></p>

       Rank:<p id = "rank"></p></h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

     <script>


    var scoress = document.getElementById('scorees');



    if (scoress == 20){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "A+";
    }else if(scoress ==19){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "A";
    }else if(scoress ==18){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML =" A-";
    }else if(scoress ==17){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "B+";
    }else if(scoress ==16){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "B";
    }else if(scoress ==15){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "B-";
    }else if(scoress ==14){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "C+";
    }else if(scoress ==13){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "C";
    }else if(scoress ==12){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "C-";
    }else if(scoress ==11){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "D+";
    }
    else if(scoress ==10){
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "D";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = "F";
    }

     <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
      document.getElementById("scoree").innerHTML = "Correct Answers: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;
    });
    </script>

     <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
      document.getElementById("scorees").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;


    });


    </script>

     <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
      document.getElementById("scoree").innerHTML = "Correct Answers: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;
    });
    </script>

     <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
      document.getElementById("scorees").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;


    });


    </script>
```

Comment: are you having problems with the grading or for setting the score?

Comment: The grade ranks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: The issue is that whenever i click button submit if the score is 14 it should be C+ but F is the one that is appearing and if i type a value in here <p id = "scores" name = "realscores">10</p> for example that 10 inside the <p> tag then D will be the rank, that's the issue I shouldn't be typing a value in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
var scoress = document.getElementById('scorees');
```

Your `scorees` contain reference of the element named `scorees`, what you actually want is it's value

you can use:

```
var scoress = document.getElementById('scorees');

// scoreesValue will contain scores you require for comparison below
var scroeesValue = scorees.getElementById("scoreesValue").textContent;
```

For updated code:
Change this

```
document.getElementById("scorees").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("scorees").innerHTML = "Your Score: <span id='scroreesValue'>" + numberOfCorrectAnswers + "</span>";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still the same thanks for the help though

Comment: It shouldn't be. Can you confirm what are you getting in `document.getElementById('scorees')` ?

Comment: It should be C+ but i get F whatever the result i get

Comment: can you `console.log(scorees)` and show us what the value is ?

Comment: <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
  document.getElementById("scoree").innerHTML = "Correct Answers: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;
});
</script>

 <script>document.getElementById("yes").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
  document.getElementById("scorees").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers;



});


</script>

Comment: I think it's because of that?

Comment: Because of this line `document.getElementById("scoree").innerHTML = "Correct Answers: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers; `

Comment: You might have to create a span for `numberOfCorrectAnswers` and use it for below `if else`

Comment: where do i create the span?

Comment: I'm quite confused I'm really sorry

Comment: Your current element is `<p id = "scores" name = "realscores">10</p>`, you will have to add `<p id = "scores" name = "realscores"><span id="scoreesValue">10</span></p>`, and you can get this span for your scorees `if else` condition. So when you add those text, you will still have a numeric value to compare

Comment: I'm sorry it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

You'll want to remove the if statement in place of either a `switch` statement or replacing it with a object (hashmap/dictionary) where you reference the key of the `score` as a key in the `grade` object

As a helpful indicator - you'll also want to correct the types in `scoress` and `scorees`

```js
const generateRank = () => {


  const scores = document.getElementById('scores').innerText;

  const grades = {
    20: "A+",
    19: "A",
    18: "A-",
    17: "B+",
    16: "B",
    15: "B-",
    14: "C+",
    13: "C",
    12: "C-",
    11: "D+",
    10: "D"
  }
  const getGrade = () => {
    return parseInt(scores) < 10 ? "F" : grades[parseInt(scores)]
  }

  const hasScore = typeof scores === "string" && !isNaN(scores) && scores.length > 0


  document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = hasScore ?  getGrade() : "no grade"
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  generateRank()
})
```

```html
<button id = "submit" name = "submit"  value = "submit" > SUBMIT </button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h3> Are you sure you want to submit? </h3>
    <button id = "yes" name = "yes" class = "yes" value = "submit" > YES </button>
    <button id = "no" name = "no" class = "no"> NO </button>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myModalLast" class="modalLast">
  <div class="modal-contentLast">
   <a href = "personal.php"> <span class="close">&times;</span> </a>

<div class = "pic">
    <img src="Logo.png" width = "150" height = "150">
</div>  
    <h3> Full name: Cathleen Joyce Imperial Almeda </h3>  
    <h3> Total items:20 <p id = "score" name = "realscores"></p> </h3>  
   <h1> <br><p id = "scores" name = "realscores">10</p>

   Rank:<p id = "rank"></p></h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's still the same

Comment: @EunhellMendoza what is your intention? - have a number in `id="scores"` and generate the rank?- I need a test case which is failing

Comment: what is your intention? - have a number in id="scores" and generate the rank? yes this is what i would like to happen, earlier when i used if conditions the results are only F and A+ but now when i used the const condition the result is undefined.

Comment: @EunhellMendoza when you edit `<p id="scores">20<p>` - the result is A+, if you edit  `<p id="scores">9<p>` the result is F

Comment: when i removed the 20 in<p id="scores">20<p> the result is undefined.??

Comment: when i changed it to 11 it became D+

Comment: what i want to do is for the id=rank to fetch the score then determine what rank it is, For example if the score is 13, If I clicked the button submit then id=rank will fetch 13 then determine what rank it is.

Comment: how do you determine the score?

Comment: @EunhellMendoza its quite late here - so sleeping now

Comment: when the radio buttons are checked the button with id yes will determine how many correct answers there are then for example the score is 12 after that id=rank will determine what rank it is and it it C-

Comment: Thank you for help it's also quite late here, Goodnight bro.

Comment: sorry bro it's still the same i really appreciate your help.